# how to validate requests in codeigniter rest server?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am using [codeigniter rest server](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver). I can't have a validation with GET request parameters. this is my validation code:

```
    $username = $this->get('username');
    $password = $this->get('password');
    $config = [
            [
                    'field' => 'username',
                    'label' => 'Username',
                    'rules' => 'required|min_length[3]|alpha_dash',
                    'errors' => [
                            'required' => 'We need both username and password',
                            'min_length'=>'Minimum Username length is 3 characters',
                            'alpha_dash'=>'You can just use a-z 0-9 _ . – characters for input',
                    ],
            ],
            [
                    'field' => 'password',
                    'label' => 'Password',
                    'rules' => 'required|min_length[6]',
                    'errors' => [
                            'required' => 'You must provide a Password.',
                            'min_length'=>'Minimum Password length is 6 characters',
                    ],
            ],
    ];
    $this->form_validation->set_data($config);
    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
    print_r($this->form_validation->error_array());
    echo "ERRR!!";
    }
    else{
        echo "SUCCESS!!";
    }
```

output is :

`Array ( ) ERRR!!`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$config = [
    [
            'field' => 'username',
            'label' => 'Username',
            'rules' => 'required|min_length[3]|alpha_dash',
            'errors' => [
                    'required' => 'We need both username and password',
                    'min_length' => 'Minimum Username length is 3 characters',
                    'alpha_dash' => 'You can only use a-z 0-9 _ . – characters for input',
            ],
    ],
    [
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'required|min_length[6]',
            'errors' => [
                    'required' => 'You must provide a Password.',
                    'min_length' => 'Minimum Password length is 6 characters',
            ],
    ],
];

$data = $this->input->get();

$this->form_validation->set_data($data);
$this->form_validation->set_rules($config);

if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
    print_r($this->form_validation->error_array());
    echo "ERROR!!";
}else{
    echo "SUCCESS!!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly set data using `$this->set_data($data);`